# Why the dnd module is not supported?

Tags: python-3.x, drag-and-drop, tkinter

I was just reading the `tkinter`  [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) in the official website and I discovered there's a module embryo called `dnd`, which allows you to drag-and-drop widgets. Will this project be supported more in the future? Is this project strictly related to tkinter GUIs development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs it will be replaced with a new DND:

> tkinter.dnd
>
> Drag-and-drop support for tkinter. This is experimental and should become deprecated when it **is replaced with the Tk DND.**

The concept should remain the same, but a lot *could* change, and I would not be terribly surprised if this happens.

[From the source:](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/python/python-3/python/Lib/lib-tk/Tkdnd.py)

> **This is very preliminary.**  I currently only support dnd *within* one
> application, between different windows (or within the same window).

As for:

> Is this project strictly related to tkinter GUIs development?

I guess, depends what you mean, there are bugs about this in the python issue tracker, and this project is related to creating GUIs, so unless I am not understanding correctly, yes it is.

Comment: dnd is essentially unchanged from early 1998.  The only open tracker issue I could find is #15346 about copying documention within file to the official docs.  The tkDND extension at Sourceforge has binaries up to 2.7, but may not have changed for over a decade.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Hmm, maybe someone should bring this up again in the issue tracker...